# Express complex function in the form $u+iv$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

One of the parts of the question I'm working on goes something like this:

> Express $z^i = \exp(i \log_I(z))$ in the form $u+iv$, where $u,v$ are real-valued functions, and the log is defined on the principal branch.

For some reason, I'm completely confused. I've seen other examples where we write $z=x+iy$, but if we do that here we get $\exp(i \log_I(x+iy))$. We know $\log_I(z)=\log(|z|)+i\arg_I(z)$, so we'd have $\log_I(x+iy)=\log(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})+i\arctan(y/x)$, as long as $\arctan(y/x)$ falls in $I=(-\pi,\pi]$.

Thus, we'd have $z^i=\exp(i (\log(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})+i\arctan(y/x)))$, but I'm not sure where to go from here/not sure if this is even on the right track.

I prefer hints over full answers. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'd say you're on the right track, since you've gotten the problem to $z^i = R(x,y)\exp(i \Phi(x,y))$ with real functions $R,\Phi$. So then you just need to get real/imaginary parts.

Comment: Maybe this way:http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFormula.html

Comment: @Semiclassical So once I have this, I follow Euler's Formula (thanks @Karl) to get $z^i = \cos[\log\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+i\arctan(y/x)]+i\sin[\log\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+i\arctan(y/x)]$. But this is still not in the form $u+iv$, with $u,v$ real because of the $i$ term within both the sine and cosine components.

Comment: @Semiclassical Nevermind - misread the question slightly. See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although $z^i$ is a multi-valued function, a branch of it is equal to
$$
z^i=\exp (i\log z)=\exp\big(i\log\lvert z\rvert+i\log(z/\lvert z\rvert)\big)
=\exp(-\vartheta)\big(\cos (\log \lvert z\rvert)+i\sin(\log \lvert z\rvert)\big),
$$
where 
$$
i\vartheta=\log\left(\frac{z}{\lvert z\rvert}\right),
$$
i.e.,
$$
\vartheta=\tan^{-1}(y/x), \,\, z=x+iy.
$$

Comment: We want $u,v$ to be real-valued functions. As in the comments above, we know that $\log(z)=\log\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+i\arctan(y/x)$. But this doesn't seems to get closer to obtaining distinct real and imaginary components.

Comment: Wow nevermind, I'm a fool. I thought the question was specifically asking for functions $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$. You are right, we only need $u(z)$ and $v(z)$. Thanks.